# Find ID of last name that created in a list

Tags: c#, list

I have the class Lion :

```
class Lion {

public string Name;
public string Age;
public int ID;
}
```

(I know there is better way to initialize ID but it's just a example)

I create a 5 lions on the main : (Suppose there is a constructor that accepts all the parameters)

```
     class Program
        {
    
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
    
 List<Lion> lions= new List<Lion>();
lions.add(new Lion ("Dopi",5,1));
lions.add(new Lion ("Gopi",5,2));
lions.add(new Lion ("Lopi",5,3));
lions.add(new Lion ("Gopi",5,4));
lions.add(new Lion ("Sopi",5,5));

    
    }
```

Now I want to get to a lion named "Gopi" and then get to his ID number, but get to the last lion created by that name.

How can i get the id of the last lion thats calling Gopi ?

I want to initialize his ID number in a separate variable.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: " but get to the last lion created by that name." what does "last" mean in this context? the one with the largest ID? is your list always as sorted as in your example? because if not, you might get unexpected results if you simply look for the "last"

Answer (score 2):

When you are asking "Last" you need to define what order you want it in. So once you order it then you can use a LINQ statement to project out the element you want and if you use `LastOrDefault()` you will get the last element that matches your query or null. If you you `Last()` you will get an exception if nothing matches your query.

So the following would work if you wanted the last when ordered by `Id`

```
lions.OrderBy(l => l.Id).LastOrDefault(x=>
    x.Name.Equals("Gopi",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Last() directly:

```
var gopiId = lions.Last(l => l.Name.Equals("Gopi")).Id;
```